# Seg fault in C ( same logic works in another program)

Tags: c, sockets, segmentation-fault

I have a dummy character array that has 3 URL information.

```
char *A[] = {"opc.tcp://localhost:4840", "opc.tcp://helloworld:4840", "opc.tcp://helloworldagain:4844"};
char *B[] = {};
char *C[] ={};
int size = sizeof(A)/sizeof(A[0]);
```

The above section is just a dummy reproduction example.

```
for(size_t i = 0; i < serverOnNetworkSize; i++) {
           UA_ServerOnNetwork *server = &serverOnNetwork[i];
           A[i] = (char *)UA_malloc(server->discoveryUrl.length+1);
           memcpy(A[i],server->discoveryUrl.data,server->discoveryUrl.length);
           A[i][server->discoveryUrl.length] = 0;
```

This is how A[] gets the URL information accurately. However, the whole program works smoothly in my system, but fails to run on docker. I tried to replicate an example by hardcoding the URL's

I need to extract the hostname and port number separately and pass it to some customized functions.

```
for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            int length = strlen(A[i]);

            B[i] = A[i] + 10;
            printf("Hostname without AA binding : %s\n", B[i]); // removes the initial binding     (opc.tcp://)
            char *p = strrchr(B[i], ':');
            int port = strtoul(p+1, NULL, 10);
            printf("Extracted port : %d\n",port);  // I get port information
             printf("Original A[i] = %s\n",A[i]);

           A[i][length-5]='\0'; //Here it fails. 
           printf("A[i] [length - 5] : next line =%s\n",A[i]); // I expect:opc:tcp//localhost
           //without initial tcp binding
           C[i] = A[i] + 10;
          printf("Hostname after removing binding : %s\n", C[i]); //expect: localhost

           if(i!=0){
                char ip_address[50];

                find_ip_address(C[i],ip_address);
       
                socketCommunication(ip_address,C[i],port);///,&B[i]);
}
}
```

global functions :

```
int find_ip_address(char *hostname, char *ip_address)
{
      struct hostent *host_name;
      struct in_addr **ipaddress;
      int count;
      if((host_name = gethostbyname(hostname)) == NULL)
      {
            herror("\nIP Address Not Found\n");
            return 1;
      }
      else
      {
            ipaddress = (struct in_addr **) host_name->h_addr_list;
            for(count = 0; ipaddress[count] != NULL; count++)
            {
                  strcpy(ip_address, inet_ntoa(*ipaddress[count]));
                  return 0;
            }
      }
      return 1;
}


void socketCommunication(char *ip_address,char *hostname, int port){
     int clientSocket,ret;
    struct  sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    char buffer[1024];  
    clientSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    if(clientSocket<0){
        printf("Error in connection \n");
        exit(1);
    }
    memset(&serverAddr,'\0',sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(port);
    serverAddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr=inet_addr(ip_address);
    ret = connect(clientSocket,(struct sockaddr*)&serverAddr,sizeof(serverAddr));
    if(ret<0){
     printf("Error");
}
```

Basically, I want the hostnames and ports to be extracted from URL, convert to IP and try to connect.

Comment: You're missing some potentially relevant code. Could you post the rest of the for loop, and the definition of socketCommunication and find_ip_address?

Comment: @Ray, it says post has too much code and does not get posted.. So basically the find_ip_address converts the hostnames to IP addresses.. The socketCommunication will try to connect to those IP and port informations

Comment: @Ray, I could post it now

Comment: Your B and C arrays are of length 0, so it is undefined behavior to use derefence B[i] or C[i]

Comment: But the failure occurs when i use A[i][length-5].. everything prior to it gets executed

Comment: Undefined behavior exhibits itself is mysterious ways.  It's not worth wondering why "everything prior to it gets executed".

Comment: Depending on stack layout any assignment to `B[i]` can destroy content of `A`. Undefined behaviour does not have to crash immediately. It can hide and wait until you don't expect it anymore. But in addition to that, most likely it crashes because `A[i][length-5]='\0'` is read only memory where your string literal is located.

Comment: Any suggestions to counter it please?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to change a constant string literal which causes segfault.
You need to either declare A as a 2d  array (`char A[][SIZE]`) or use dynamic memory allocation.

AND the code has other problems too:

- B and C are not allocated which can cause runtime errors.
- `B[i] = A[i] + 10;` not readable and confusing, better to use pointers instead

Comment: Hello @saeedkazemi, could you look into my edit please?

Comment: @RakshanPremsagarKapikad I'm not sure which code block is actually used in your program.
the segmentation fault can be caused by different problems, For example, if the length of A[i] is less than 5, then a[i][length - 5] can cause the segfault.
maybe the memory allocation fails and returns NULL (although it is not probably)
The provided code is not sufficient and clear enough to reason about.
I recommend uploading your code somewhere and posting a link to it here.

Comment: "elements of A are not necessarily of equal size" ... that's where you're wrong. Elements of an array are, by definition, all of equal size. The elements in this case are pointers.